# Call web api post method in a loop

Tags: angularjs

I need to send a big json array to web service. The array contain 20000 records. I hope the best method to send the large data to API is part by part. So I'm planning to send 1000 records at a time. In the success method of the async post method I'm calling the same method. I'll check the limit in the success method before recurring the function

But my question is this is a good approach. Is there any better method than this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set your API to receive the amount of data that you want to retrieve and the offset. Something like: get( amount: 1000, from: 2000).

Comment: why do you want to split it? I don't think there is a limit to how much you can send, it just takes longer

Comment: @AlekseySolovey you mean if a JSON array with 20,000 records can send in a single post method?

Comment: @user1849993 you can read [some articles](https://joshzeigler.com/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json) about that elsewhere